# New to coding and getters and setters are not working to a new class?

Tags: java, methods, getter-setter

So I have been writing a code for a lab in which we need to create a class titled payroll where we have the getters and setters for name, address, pay and hours worked and then create a method to print the address and the name and another method to calculate hours worked x pay and print that with address and name on another class titled demoPayroll. My getters and setters arent transferring over to the demoPayroll though. This is the code I have. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DemoPayroll {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Payroll newEmpInfoObject = new Payroll();

        System.out.println("Enter name");
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        String name = keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter Address");
        String address = keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter Hourly Pay");
        double payrate = keyboard.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Enter Hours Worked");
        double hours = keyboard.nextDouble();

        newEmpInfoObject.printEmpInfo();
        newEmpInfoObject.getGrossPayEarned();
    }
}

public class Payroll {
    private String name;
    private String address;
    private double payrate;
    private double hours;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public double getPayrate() {
        return payrate;
    }

    public void setPayrate(double payrate) {
        this.payrate = payrate;
    }

    public double getHours() {
        return hours;
    }

    public void setHours(double hours) {
        this.hours = hours;
    }

    public Object printEmpInfo() {
        System.out.println(name);
        System.out.println(address);
        return address;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you calling your setters?

Comment: You don't _call_ any setter.

Comment: You never use your getters and setters. The only methods you invoke on your `Payroll` object are `printEmpInfo()` and `getGrossPayEarned()`. Also, please tidy up the code in your question.

Comment: [The Java™ Tutorials: Using Objects](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/usingobject.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I might think you have copied the program from an external source,
since there is lots of compilation errors.
Anyways...
try this this might work...

import java.util.Scanner;

public class DemoPayroll {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Payroll newEmpInfoObject = new Payroll();

    System.out.println("Enter name");
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    String name = keyboard.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter Address");
    String address = keyboard.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter Hourly Pay");
    double payrate = keyboard.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Enter Hours Worked");
    double hours = keyboard.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Enter Weeks");
    int week = keyboard.nextInt();

    Payroll pay=new Payroll();

    pay.printEmpInfo(name,address);
    System.out.println(pay.getGrossPayEarned(payrate,hours,week));
}
```

}

class Payroll {

```
private double payrate;
private double hours;

public Object printEmpInfo(String name,String address) {
    System.out.println(name);
    System.out.println(address);
    return address;
}
public double getGrossPayEarned(double payrate,double hours,int week) {
    return (hours)*((hours/week)*52)/12;
}
```

}